# Layout com 3 colunas em CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Alguém sabe onde encontro material onde possa ter uma norte de como fazer esse efeito de cor nas fotos e de como dividir em 3 colunas com textos sobre a imagem de fundo?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de aplicar efeitos em fotos com css. Você pode tentar com a propriedade filter ou aplicar um gradient para esse seu exemplo.

Propriedade filter: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Sobre divisão em 3 colunas, a maneira mais popular e fácil de se trabalhar hoje em dia são com sistemas de Grid ou FlexBox(Suportado em alguns navegadores somente nas versões mais recentes).

O BootStrap tem um sistema de Grid em 12 colunas bem fácil de se trabalhar de uma olhada.

http://getbootstrap.com.br/css/#grid